# Hide an element when scroll to specific class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Used this JQuery code to have a sticky "Go to top" button:

```
//sticky back-to-top button
(function (t) {
  t(window).bind("scroll", function () {
    500 < t(this).scrollTop()
      ? t(".back-to-top").fadeIn(400)
      : t(".back-to-top").fadeOut(400);
  }),
    t(".back-to-top").click(function () {
      t("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 500);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

this code works correctly.
but i want when this sticky button reaches a specific class called "go-top", disappears. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I don't understand your problem completely but using  `addClass` or `removeClass` jquery method should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interception observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) so when the target element with said class is in view, it triggers the callback to hide the button.

Example: The code might not be exact but it is meant to point in the direction to follow.

```
let options = {
    root: document.querySelector('.go-top'),
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
 }
let prevRatio = 0.0;
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

let target = document.querySelector('#back-to-top-button');
observer.observe(target);

function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > prevRatio) {
      entry.target.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor = "block";
    }

    prevRatio = entry.intersectionRatio;
  });
}
```

Let me know how it goes...

You can switch the `root` to `null` but this makes the button disappear as soon as the element with the class is in the viewport

Comment: Thanks shammahk but I Just want when back-to-top class reaches the go-top button, back-to-top class going to hide then when user scroll to top again, it shows itself.

Comment: Can you make a sandbox with your code so I can work with it? Or repo if that's possible